# Getting different results using selenium and iFrames on Firefox 63, Chrome 69 and Chrome 70

Tags: chromedriver, firefoxdriver, selenium3, katalon

I wrote a test using Katalon Studio 5.8.0.
My application under test contains a iFrame.
Fortunately, both the iFrame and its children are identified using unique attributes.

So, the following code was correctly running on Firefox 63 and Chrome 69

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
WebElement elementFrame = null;
elementFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id = 'monerisFrame']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(elementFrame);
List<WebElement> ElementList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type = 'tel']"));
System.out.println("iFrame elements: " + ElementList.size());
```

Console output: **iFrame elements: 2**

Unfortunately, since my Chrome got updated from 69 to 70, the same exact code returns zero instead of 2. Same AUT, same code...

Console output: **iFrame elements: 0**

I presume Chrome 70 is doing something different with iFrames.

Any clues on how to work around this issue without downgrading to Chrome 69 ?

Comment: Have you updated chrome driver as well?

Comment: Not yet. I will try right now.

Answer (score 2):

> Have you updated chrome driver as well? – Alexey R. Oct 30 '18 at
>   16:13

Resolved !

Upgrading to Chromedriver 2.43 did the trick.

Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.43
Supports Chrome v69-71

Changes include:
[...]
Fixed Switch to Frame is not spec compliant
[...]

Thanks to Alexey R.

Comment: Why don't you link Alexey's comment/post? Might be helpful for others.

Comment: Done ! Thanks for the tip @MateMrše